# How do I interpret the corrupted file information produced by SFC?

Tags: windows, debug

Running a scan with the SFC (system file checker) produces entries in the CBS.log file.

```
sfc /scannow
```

Microsoft recommends running the findstr (find string) command with the c switch which searches for specified string within the log file. The result is output to a new file on current users desktop.

```
findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log
```

Now, this is what I got.

```
2013-06-13 18:50:15, Info                  CSI    00000006 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2013-06-13 18:50:15, Info                  CSI    00000007 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 18:50:17, Info                  CSI    00000009 [SR] Verify complete

ROWS THAT I SKIPPED (NO CORRUPTED FILES)

2013-06-13 18:53:43, Info                  CSI    000000d1 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2013-06-13 18:53:43, Info                  CSI    000000d2 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 18:53:47, Info                  CSI    000000d4 [SR] Verify complete
2013-06-13 18:53:47, Info                  CSI    000000d5 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2013-06-13 18:53:47, Info                  CSI    000000d6 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 18:53:51, Info                  CSI    000000d8 [SR] Verify complete

ROWS THAT I SKIPPED (NO CORRUPTED FILES)

2013-06-13 18:58:25, Info                  CSI    0000016b [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2013-06-13 18:58:25, Info                  CSI    0000016c [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 18:58:35, Info                  CSI    0000016e [SR] Verify complete
2013-06-13 18:58:36, Info                  CSI    0000016f [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2013-06-13 18:58:36, Info                  CSI    00000170 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 18:58:43, Info                  CSI    00000172 [SR] Verify complete
2013-06-13 18:58:44, Info                  CSI    00000173 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2013-06-13 18:58:44, Info                  CSI    00000174 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 18:58:50, Info                  CSI    00000176 [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:58{29}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32\sv-SE"\[l:20{10}]"secpol.msc" from store
2013-06-13 18:58:51, Info                  CSI    00000179 [SR] Verify complete
2013-06-13 18:58:52, Info                  CSI    0000017a [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2013-06-13 18:58:52, Info                  CSI    0000017b [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 18:59:07, Info                  CSI    0000017d [SR] Verify complete

ROWS THAT I SKIPPED (NO CORRUPTED FILES)

2013-06-13 19:00:38, Info                  CSI    000001a8 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2013-06-13 19:00:38, Info                  CSI    000001a9 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 19:00:44, Info                  CSI    000001ae [SR] Verify complete
2013-06-13 19:00:45, Info                  CSI    000001af [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2013-06-13 19:00:45, Info                  CSI    000001b0 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 19:00:50, Info                  CSI    000001b2 [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:42{21}]"Wdf01000Uninstall.mof" from store
2013-06-13 19:00:50, Info                  CSI    000001b4 [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:24{12}]"Wdf01000.mof" from store
2013-06-13 19:00:51, Info                  CSI    000001b8 [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:42{21}]"Wdf01000Uninstall.mof" from store
2013-06-13 19:00:51, Info                  CSI    000001ba [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:24{12}]"Wdf01000.mof" from store
2013-06-13 19:00:53, Info                  CSI    000001bf [SR] Verify complete
2013-06-13 19:00:53, Info                  CSI    000001c0 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2013-06-13 19:00:53, Info                  CSI    000001c1 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 19:01:01, Info                  CSI    000001c3 [SR] Verify complete

ROWS THAT I SKIPPED (NO CORRUPTED FILES)

2013-06-13 19:08:58, Info                  CSI    0000034d [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2013-06-13 19:08:58, Info                  CSI    0000034e [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 19:09:06, Info                  CSI    00000350 [SR] Verify complete
2013-06-13 19:09:06, Info                  CSI    00000351 [SR] Verifying 81 (0x0000000000000051) components
2013-06-13 19:09:06, Info                  CSI    00000352 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 19:09:10, Info                  CSI    00000354 [SR] Verify complete
2013-06-13 19:09:10, Info                  CSI    00000355 [SR] Repairing 3 components
2013-06-13 19:09:10, Info                  CSI    00000356 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 19:09:10, Info                  CSI    00000358 [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:42{21}]"Wdf01000Uninstall.mof" from store
2013-06-13 19:09:10, Info                  CSI    0000035a [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:24{12}]"Wdf01000.mof" from store
2013-06-13 19:09:10, Info                  CSI    0000035e [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:58{29}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32\sv-SE"\[l:20{10}]"secpol.msc" from store
2013-06-13 19:09:11, Info                  CSI    00000361 [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:42{21}]"Wdf01000Uninstall.mof" from store
2013-06-13 19:09:11, Info                  CSI    00000363 [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:24{12}]"Wdf01000.mof" from store
2013-06-13 19:09:11, Info                  CSI    00000367 [SR] Repair complete
2013-06-13 19:09:11, Info                  CSI    00000368 [SR] Committing transaction
2013-06-13 19:09:11, Info                  CSI    00000369 [SR] Cannot commit interactively, there are boot critical components being repaired
2013-06-13 19:09:11, Info                  CSI    0000036a [SR] Repairing 3 components
2013-06-13 19:09:11, Info                  CSI    0000036b [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-06-13 19:09:11, Info                  CSI    0000036d [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:42{21}]"Wdf01000Uninstall.mof" from store
2013-06-13 19:09:11, Info                  CSI    0000036f [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:24{12}]"Wdf01000.mof" from store
2013-06-13 19:09:11, Info                  CSI    00000373 [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:58{29}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32\sv-SE"\[l:20{10}]"secpol.msc" from store
2013-06-13 19:09:11, Info                  CSI    00000376 [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:42{21}]"Wdf01000Uninstall.mof" from store
2013-06-13 19:09:11, Info                  CSI    00000378 [SR] Repairing corrupted file [ml:58{29},l:56{28}]"\??\C:\Windows\system32\wbem"\[l:24{12}]"Wdf01000.mof" from store
2013-06-13 19:09:12, Info                  CSI    0000037c [SR] Repair complete
```

How do I interpret the following line:

```
Repairing corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:58{29}]"\??\C:\Windows\System32\sv-SE"\[l:20{10}]"secpol.msc" from store
```

What is **ml**, and what is **l** indicating? Why are there two double question marks before the search path? What does SR stand for? What is the "store"?

If you know of a TechNet or MSDN article or some other web page that addresses this question please post a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the information you are asking for is described on [MSKB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928228).

CBS.log is not only used by sfc.exe, so sfc.exe adds the `[SR]` as a marker to all lines it writes. This lets you identify which lines have been written by sfc.exe.

The pathes given in the log file are low level filesystem pathes/object names which the object manager knows how to handle. The `\??\` is an object directory created by the object manager for device names. In this object directory the Windows subsystem creates a symbolic link for C: to the harddisk that is mounted as C:. You can find a little bit more information [here](http://help.wugnet.com/windows/Registry-Entry-path-preceded-ftopict630476.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_%28Windows%29). SysInternals has a good tool Winobj.exe on their [web page](http://live.sysinternals.com/) where you can view all the objects.

The "store" used to be the folder %SystemRoot%\System32\DllCache, see [MSKB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236995), since Windows Vista it is located at %WinDir%\WinSxS\Backup, also see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Resource_Protection).

I have no idea what **ml** and **l** are standing for, but the values given after ml and l suggest that they are length information for the string that is following ('l:<length in bytes>{<length in Unicode characters>}"the string"').